# Error al concatenar 2 dataframe en pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

zz = zz.rename(columns={0:'producto'})
zz

yy = yy.rename(columns={0:'precio'})
yy

Para ambos casos se tiene los mismos numeros e filas.
Cuando trato de concatenar me sale error, a que se debe?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué error? Yo veo que está haciendo correctamente lo que le has pedido. Fíjate que un dataframe en su index tiene solo números impares y el otro sólo números pares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás concatenando dos dataframes cuyo único campo en común es el índice, pero un dataframe solo tiene números pares, y el otro solo tiene números impares, así que el nuevo dataframe tiene TODOS los datos de ambos dataframes, pero en las filas pares solo tienes los datos de uno de ellos, y viceversa.

Para solucionarlo, antes de concatenar, puedes resetear los índices de ambos dataframes, así:

```
Tu_DataFrame.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

El argumento `'inplace'`, modifica tu dataframe, en lugar de hacer copia.
Después puedes concatenarlos sin problemas. Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado